# What's the word for things naturally not attracting or mixing with each other?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to use one word to express how people who have very different world views are naturally pushed apart, like water and oil.
It's not quite repulsion, but it's the natural avoidance. Thoughts?

Example below:
I don't find them interesting and the feeling is mutual. So I'm happy for this natural [insert word here]

Comment: Please read the guidance given in the  [single-word-requests tag description](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests). [Edit] your question and give us a specific sentence where you would use this word.

Comment: What register do you want? You can’t use *immiscibility* in a regular English sentence because it’s too high-falutin’ a way of saying *unmixability*.

Comment: I would have thought "a natural elusion" was a good middle-register term. (Not that I've ever heard it used!)

Comment: @tchrist historically, there was a legal concept called the "doctrine of immiscibility", as explained here: https://books.google.com/books?id=7EQwAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA683&dq=%22doctrine+of++immiscibility%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4-aTNtNDYAhWjz4MKHXNTDqcQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22doctrine%20of%20%20immiscibility%22&f=false  "immiscibility" has been used for social, racial and religious groups.

Comment: Avoid posting questions that do not provide clear criteria for useful answers – criteria that guide both answering and voting. This applies to word requests that lack: (i) objective criteria for accepting answers, including connotation, register, and part of speech; (ii) exact context – generally we want the sentence you’re writing; and (iii) details of research you’ve already done (trips to the thesaurus, etc.) including solutions you’ve already rejected, and why.

Comment: When a word request attracts a long list of ideas, that is a clear signal that either the criteria are unclear or the question is more of a poll or request for a list of things, neither of which are a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. See: See: “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity – ELU Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”; “[Real Questions Have Answers – SE Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.

Comment: *rejection*, *spurning*, *snubbing*

Comment: There is a tendency to put -phobic at the end of things these days, as in 'hydrophobic'.

Comment: Aversion or Disregard would also work well in this case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here, 'Repulsion' can be used. But it's a strong word. In simpler cases you can go with the words 'Aversion', 'Disinclination'.

"I don't find them interesting and the feeling is mutual. So I'm happy for this natural **disinclination/aversion**"

Comment: I think *aversion* fits the question best.

Comment: *Enmity* might work also, but seems too strong for what the asker wants to say.

Comment: Yup, such a simple word. Aversion seems to suit most indeed. Thank you

Comment: You're Welcome. All have suggested the correct words, given the context. It just depends how intensely we intend to convey our feelings.

Answer (score 33):

How about **immiscibility**? 
This extends the analogy from chemistry of mixing, that you cited regarding oil and water. 
But your suggested sentence might read a little better, if it relaxed the single-word requirement and was something like:-

I don't find them interesting and the feeling is mutual. So I'm happy for us to be socially less than **miscible**.

Ref [miscible (in Chemistry)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscibility)

Answer (score 4):

segregation

For example from the [Journal of Psychology](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1324&bih=729&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1900%2Ccd_max%3A1999&tbm=bks&ei=73pXWrGzBc3XzwL9uKPwCA&q=%22natural%20segregation%22&oq=%22natural%20segregation%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...26839.28609.0.28946.7.7.0.0.0.0.63.329.7.7.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.jeN4NzGoz0o) :

> Natural segregation occurs everywhere in nature, in business (all auto agencies in same neighborhood). Natural segregation allows like to enjoy like.

And from [Sociology](https://books.google.com/books?id=2bJHAAAAYAAJ&q=%22natural%20segregation%22&dq=%22natural%20segregation%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwijpZHOltDYAhXO7VMKHcClDuU4ChDoAQgmMAA):

> Natural segregation is found wherever cliques form.

Comment: This is probably the best answer in terms of describing self selection amongst people with with incompatible views. Immiscible is also good but I would use self selection or segregation.

Answer (score 3):

Heterogeneous (or heterogeneity in your example)

In the sciences it would be a term for an oil/water mixture; in language it would be a term for a diverse mixture.

Answer (score 2):

***Dissociation*** is a state of being separate ("not mixing") without the need to be *repulsive*.

> I don't find them interesting and the feeling is mutual. So I'm happy
>   for this natural ***dissociation***.

ODO:

> **[dissociation](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/dissociation)**
>   *NOUN*
>   **1** The disconnection or separation of something from something else or the state of being disconnected.
>
> ‘the dissociation between the executive and the judiciary is the
>   legacy of the Act of Settlement’
>
> ‘What Shiang herself experiences in Paris, as an almost accidental
>   tourist who doesn't speak French, is severe dislocation and even
>   dissociation.’

Answer (score 2):

What you are expressing in your first sentence is the **division** of humanity based on contrary ideologies.

Therefore, in your sentence I suggest :

> So I'm happy for this natural **division**.

[Britpolitics :](http://www.britpolitics.co.uk/a-level-uk-political-parties-uk-conservative-party-divisions)

> ... ideological divisions in the conservative party ...

Answer (score 2):

**Siloing**

In a different context - teams of software developers - we say that we're *siloing*. For example, we have a team of Windows and Mac developers, but the Windows folks aren't doing anything to participate on the Mac side, and vice versa, so they're forming silos. The idea should conjure visions of grain silos. A farmer might have a corn silo and a bean silo, and certainly wouldn't want the contents mixed. In software development, siloing is considered a Bad Thing, or *process smell* and we might counter it with (again, thanks to the farmers) cross-pollination.

I haven't heard it used outside the software development context, but it seems like it would be a perfect fit for the situation you give, and has the appropriate negative connotations.

The downside is that your audience is probably not all software developers, and they won't know what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Orthogonality.

So e.g.:
*I don't find them interesting and the feeling is mutual. So I'm happy for this natural **orthogonality**.*

This uses an analogy from Mathematics.
More specifically, in the Taxonomy sense, as noted under 
[mathematics, orthogonality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality)

Comment: To me orthogonal is not "of similar nature, but distinct", but "having nothing to do with each other", so apples and oranges.

Answer (score -2):

how about Eccentric ???
eccentric basically means the one who is out of the circle.
let's put it in a simple words, consider a group of people having a common or we can say usual interests/ doing ordinary and same things.And now if a person who does not match with this interest then we can say he is eccentric.

Comment: the asker wants a name for a reciprocal incompatibility. Eccentricity might well be applicable to one part and not to the other(s).

Answer (score -2):

**Polarity**

> 1.2 The state of having two opposite or contradictory tendencies, opinions, or aspects.
>    ‘the polarity between male and female’
>    count noun ‘the Cold War's neat polarities can hardly be carried on’

[Polarity](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/polarity): Oxford Living Dictionaries online

Answer (score -2):

Incongruous? It means:

> not in harmony or keeping with the surroundings or other aspects of
>   something